# How to get HTML from Jquery form builder and store it in database

Tags: html, jquery, django

Iam bulding a survey website,where the user can create their own forms.My project contains 2 side , create-form where the surveyer can create the form and user side where they can fill the form , and i am using django  on both sides.
For starters iam using jquery form builder:

```
<div id="fb-editor"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document.getElementById('fb-editor')).formBuilder();
});
</script>
```

My plan is to take the HTML code of the generated `form` and store it in a database, like `firebase` and then re-generate the form on user-side.So i need help on how to extract the HTML of the generated form and Is it the right way to do this thing or Is there any alternative "Django" way on doing this thing.

Comment: Store  the JSON format and using render option to view the form